# Kali Linux dual boot installation: unusable partition

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, kali-linux

So I was trying to install Kali Linux in dual boot with Windows 10 on my laptop but when I got to select the partition and make the swap area or whatever it is the 30 GB I removed from my windows partition which in Windows show up as free were marked as unusable and no other information! Please help!

[image: A list of 4 primary partitions, followed by a 32.2 GB chunk of free space]

EDIT: Solution no.1 from bellow worked for me! (obviously)

Answer (score 0):

Your disk is using MBR scheme, which is limited to 4 primary partitions.

There are 3 ways to work around this:

1. Backup the 4th partition, delete it, create an extended partition spanning entire remaining space. Inside the extended partition create a logical disk and restore 4th partition content into it. Then you can add additional partitions inside the extended partition - there's no limit to their number.
2. Convert your disk to GPT scheme. This operation is usually relatively easy on modern Windows versions using the `mbr2gpt` tool, unless you have one of these few configurations that aren't supported. Your motherboard must be based on UEFI (a BIOS successor).
3. **Recommended:** give up dual boot, install Kali in a VM on Windows. This will consume Windows's disk space as it's needed, up to a configured limit.

Answer (score -2):

There is an easy way to install dual windows you just need to download easeup partition maker with license key and convert your disk from dynamic to basic then then go to disk management and create unlocated space again it will show your free space and also kali will detect your free space.